# How can I use other environments

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

OpenAI's `universe` is a awesome library, Since the code

```
# coding: utf-8
import gym
import universe # register the universe environments

env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')
env.configure(remotes=1) # automatically creates a local docker container
observation_n = env.reset()
while True:
    action_n = [[('KeyEvent', 'ArrowUp', True)] for ob in observation_n] # your agent here
    observation_n, reward_n, done_n, info = env.step(action_n)
    env.render()
```

Has provided the "DuskDrive-v0" environment, and How can I use other environments?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to this page:
https://universe.openai.com/envs#flash_games

Select a game, copy the title of the game:
flashgames.HarvestDay-v0

and replace it in your code:
env = gym.make('flashgames.DuskDrive-v0')